# How to search a specific transaction in all blocks quickly

Tags: blockchain

How can I search a transaction in a blockchain quickly, which may contains thousands of blocks?

Comment: Hi, this question might not be suitable for StackOverflow, as it does not seem to relate to any code, but more to the overall workings of blockchain. If it is suitable, please provide some code sample you have questions about.

Comment: most of the blockchain implements an rpc framework, you can use what you have transaction id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A block explorer is what you need.
A block explorer allows you to search and navigate through the blockchain.

How does a block explorer accomplish this? It does all this work:

- Connects to blockchain nodes and listens for blocks Parses blocks and
- Indexes the block, tarnsaction information into a Database
- Provides a webservice that allows you to query this database

Also look at this wonderful [answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/58844/how-block-explorer-technology-works)